# Is there a way to specify which form to use as onFormSubmit trigger when multiple forms linked to one sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I Currently have two completely different forms providing two different functions linked to the same spreadsheet (and they need to be because I use data from both).
I want to be able to distinguish functions which are triggered, one function called `emailQuote()` for instance when one of the forms is submitted, but if the other form is submitted, I want to trigger the `scanForQuoters()` function that I already have, is there a way to do this please?

I am simply using Google App Script with script tool to create my own functions, and there is the ability to trigger them on several parameters such as `onEdit` or `onFormSubmit`. It is being able to use onFormSubmit and distinguish on which form submit, which is what I am concerned about.

[image: See Image of triggers here]

Comment: There's only one onformSubmit trigger.  You can us range.getSheet() to determine which sheet is being written to and from that deduce which form is being submitted.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't but you can add a condition based on the destination sheet. The following example use `switch` but you could use if..else or any other way to handle conditional expressions.

NOTE: `e` is used for the on form submit event object. `e.range` is available for on form submit trigger for a spreadsheet.

```js
function respondToOnFormSubmit(e){
  switch(e.range.getSheet().getName()){
    case 'Sheet1':
      // Stuff to be done when the submissions responses are sent to Sheet1
      break;
    case 'Sheet2':
      // Stuff to be done when the submissions responses are sent to Sheet2
      break;
    default:
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

Resources

- [Event Objects | Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Answer (score 1):

The Form that is linked to the Sheet that just got the answers can be retrieved as follows.

```
function myFormSubmitFnc(e) {
  var form,sheet,urlOfLinked;
  
  sheet = e.range.getSheet();//Get the sheet tab that the Form answers were written to  
  urlOfLinked = sheet.getFormUrl();//Returns the URL for the form that sends its 
  //responses to this sheet, or null if this sheet has no associated form

  form = FormApp.openByUrl(urlOfLinked);//The the Form that set the answers in the Sheet
};
```